# Apply vendor prefixes to Javascript styling

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, for-loop

I'm applying transform styles using javascript. I wanted to create a simpler way to loop through vendor prefixes when applying the style. So I created an array with the prefixes in, then a for loop like so:

```
var transformVendor = [
  'transform',
  'OTransform',
  'msTransform',
  'MozTransform',
  'WebkitTransform'
];

for (var i=0; i<transformVendor.length; i++) {
  Element.style.transformVendor[i] = 'translate(10px,10px)';
}
```

But this isn't working. Have I applied the for loop incorrectly?

Comment: Please define "isn't working". Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change your syntax to something like this:

```
Element.style[ transformVendor[i] ]
```

Instead of using the normal dot notation, here I'm accessing the property using an array like syntax.

The two methods are usually interchangeable, but sometimes when the property name you need is dynamic, it makes sense to use the array syntax because you can just drop in a dynamic string as the key.